# $\{\sigma\in S_n;\sigma(n)=n\}$ is isomorphic to $S_{n-1}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I'm trying to prove that the set $K=\{\sigma\in S_n;\sigma(n)=n\}$ is a subgroup of $S_n$ which is isomorphic to $S_{n-1}$.

In order to prove that this set is a subgroup of $S_n$, I did this: $\alpha$, $\beta\in K$, then $\alpha\beta^{-1}(n)=\sigma(n)=n\implies \alpha\beta^{-1}\in K$, then we can conclude easily that K is a subgroup of $S_n$. Is that approach correct?

And to prove the second part of this question I know intuitively it's true but I couldn't find an isomorphic function between $K$ and $S_{n-1}$.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach is fine, but you forgot to show/mention that $K\ne\emptyset$.
On the other hand, specifying the isomorphism $\phi\colon K\to S_{n-1}$ would also have shown that $K$ is a subgroup.
Yes, $\phi$ is so simple one might overlook it. Simply let $\phi(\sigma)=\sigma|_{\{1,\ldots,n-1\}}$ or more explicitly
$$\begin{align}\phi(\sigma)\colon\{1,\ldots,n-1\}&\to\{1,\ldots,n-1\}\\x&\mapsto \sigma(x)\end{align} $$

Comment: Can I argue just saying that id  of $S_{n-1}$ is in K to prove that K is nonempty? thank you for your answer

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in one step. More generally, let $X$ be any set, and $x_0 \in X$. Define the map $\alpha : \mathrm{Sym}(X \setminus \{x_0\}) \to \mathrm{Sym}(X)$ by $\alpha(f)|_{X \setminus \{x_0\}}=f$ and $\alpha(f)(x_0)=x_0$. Verify that $\alpha$ is a well-defined group homomorphism, which is injective. Conclude that the image is a subgroup, namely $\{f \in \mathrm{Sym}(X) : f(x_0)=x_0\}$, isomorphic to $\mathrm{Sym}(X \setminus \{x_0\})$.